# Frozen Video After An Update on the Display

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to make a gun camera with a basic targeting system. The program draws a rectangle on the video display for encapsulating target. Additionally, I've added some fire control mechanism:

- If the operator presses <kbd>F</kbd> on the keyboard, the weapon is fired and a cross is drawn inside the rectangle
- If the operator presses <kbd>C</kbd>, the fire is ceased, the cross is erased and the rectangle gets its original state

The relevant Python source code for this project is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

capture = cv.VideoCapture(1)

capture.set(3, 512)
capture.set(4, 512)

display_width  = capture.get(3)
display_height = capture.get(4)

tlccx = round(display_width / 3)
tlccy = round(display_height / 3)
lrccx = round(2 * display_width / 3)
lrccy = round(2 * display_height / 3)

if not capture.isOpened():

   print("An error occured! The camera cannot be opened.")
   exit()

while True:

      retrieve, frame = capture.read()

      if not retrieve:

         print("The frame cannot be retrieved (stream end?). Exiting ...")
         break

      gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      frame1 = cv.cvtColor(gray, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
      frame2 = cv.rectangle(frame1, (tlccx, tlccy), (lrccx, lrccy), (0, 255, 0), 3)
    
      cv.imshow("Display", frame2)

      if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("f"):

         frame3 = cv.line(frame2, (tlccx, tlccy), (lrccx, lrccy), (0, 255, 0), 3)
         frame4 = cv.line(frame3, (tlccx, lrccy), (lrccx, tlccy), (0, 255, 0), 3)

         while True:

               cv.imshow("Display", frame4)

               if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("c"):

                  break

      cv.imshow("Display", frame2)
            
      if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):

         break

capture.release()

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Functionality examples:

- The video display without the cross

  [image]
- The video display with the cross

  [image]

The problem is that whenever I press <kbd>F</kbd>, the cross is placed into the rectangle, but the video stream freezes.

Why does this malfunction occur? And how can I sort it out so that the video continues to stream while placing the cross into the rectangle? Additionally, when I press <kbd>Q</kbd> for shutting down the display, this window only closes after pressing the button more than once. Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: this is a basic programming problem. the nested loop NOT reading new pictures, only showing the same old one, shouldn't have surprised you, because that is precisely what you wrote in your program. please learn how to debug programs. that is a basic skill required in programming. as to your problem: you need a variable to keep the "state". key presses change the variable. the value of the variable decides whether you draw the cross or not.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your suggestions, I've sorted it out by placing frame reading sequence and the other upcoming codes into the nested while loop as you've noted that this while loop is just making use of a frame rather than a picture stream. Maybe there are other solutions but this one saves the day and performs okay.

Answer (score 0):

The window freezes because you are trying to add second while loop in the main loop.

The function `capture.release()` is responsible to keep the main window running, since, when your second `while` loop is trigged the cursor never reaches to the `capture.release()` function and hence your window freezes and as soon as the second while loop gets terminated by pressing "c" the first while gets invoked and the window starts to run again.

Same for the "q" press function first press exits the second while loop and second "q' press exits the main while loop.

I am not sure what your programming requirements are but still you want to show firing process why don't you just remove the second while loop. you wont need the c press function at all.

```
if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("f"):
     frame3 = cv.line(frame2, (tlccx, tlccy), (lrccx, lrccy), (0, 255, 0), 3)
     frame4 = cv.line(frame3, (tlccx, lrccy), (lrccx, tlccy), (0, 255, 0), 3)
     cv.imshow("Display", frame4)            
if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
     break
```

`

and if that not what you want the my advice would be not to use two while loops in this in open cv
may be multithreading can be used to show the cross for particular time period and then automatically go to original frame.

Hope this would have helped you.

Comment: @Siddesh Khadapkar Thank you for your attention and response. I've decided to let the cross appear to an extent which is determined by myself i.e. I want it to appear until I press "C". This is the reason why I'd added a conditional block for this button. Nevertheless, thank you for your advice.